# Inconsistent date between SSAS Cube and Tabular Model

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, tabular, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

I have a very weird problem. I have built a tabular model which takes data from a SSAS cube. In the data source cube, there is a column called "Process Date" and it is in UK date format (dd/mm/yyyy). When I bring this column into my model, the dates are messed up, where the date and month values are swapped for some dates!

Below are the images to illustrate this and I have highlighted one particular date in red. In the data source SSAS cube, the date is 12/02/2019, and when it goes to the tabular model, this date beomces 02/12/2019. I have added a check_month column in the tabular model and found that the tabular model thinks its December i.e. the day/month has been swapped!

[data source date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82XIM.jpg)

[model date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9aiP.jpg)

Thank you

JC

Edit: This has been solved by changing the Locale Identifier in the connection. See the comment in the answer below by userfl89. This is due to the data source cube is using a different locale (US English) then what I am using in the model, changing the locale identifier will override this and hence solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format can be defined from SSDT.  Highlight the date column and go to the properties window (press F4).  For the `Data Format` property select the desired date format.  If you need a date format that's not listed a calculated column using the `FORMAT` function can be created based off the original column, with the data type of this column then set to `Date`.  An example of this is below.  Additionally, confirm the Locale Identifier (LCID) in SSDT.  This can by viewed by selecting **Model** > **Existing Connections** > **Edit** > **Build** > **All** > then the **Locale Identifier** property.  The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/languages-and-collations-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) provides details in regards to identifying the correct LCID.

```
=FORMAT('Process'[Process Date], "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and it does not work. I believe it is not simplily the format has been changed, instead the "day" and "month" value has been swapped when it is queried from the source cube. Also I have noticed that this only happen for the date that has a month valule <= 12 i.e. if I have 5th March 2018, in my original source it is 5/3/2018, and in the tabular model it becomes 3/5/2018, and under the format "dd-MM-yyyy" it is giving me 03-05-2018. If it is 13th March 2018, in the source it will be 13/3/2018, and in the model it is also 13/3/2018.

Comment: Have you tried either changing the data type of the Process Date column to text then using the calculated column, or importing the process date column as text (i.e. cast to VARCHAR in SQL statement) then applying the calculated column?

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. I have tried puting the "Process Date" column as text. By doing this all the dates were in US format. Then I do the calculated column =FORMAT('Process'[Process Date], "dd-MM-yyyy") which does not result in any changes. I tried doing =FORMAT(Datevalue('Process'[Process Date], "dd-MM-yyyy")), which result in the old problem (day value <=12 getting swapped with month).

Comment: It could be related to the Locale Identifier in the connection.  This property can be found by going to Model > Existing Connections > Edit > Build > All > then the Locale Identifier property.  The link at the end of this comment details the specifics further.  Another option would be to separate the date parts in the SQL and force date part mapping using the DATE function, then put this inside FORMAT, however this would use quite a bit more resources.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/languages-and-collations-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I went on to change the Locale Identifier of the connection and set it to 2057 (English, United Kingdom) and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I added this to my answer to better explain what the cause of this was.